# Как вернуть результат post запроса (axios) в состояние (react)?

Tags: javascript, сервер, post, reactjs

Подскажите, как вернуть значение переменно data из такого состояния?

```
componentDidMount: function() {
        var _this = this;
        this.serverRequest = 
        axios.post(
            'https://suggestions.dadata.ru/suggestions/api/4_1/rs/suggest/party', // url
            { 'query': 'Пилот' }, // data
            {
                headers: { 
                    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
                    'Accept':        'application/json',
                    'Authorization': 'Token ' + 'МойТокенКлюч',
                    'X-Secret':'МойСекретныйКлюч',
                },
                // `withCredentials` indicates whether or not cross-site Access-Control requests
                // should be made using credentials
             } // config

        )
        .then(function (response) {
          let data = JSON.parse( response.request.response );
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
           console.log(error);
        });
        console.log(this.serverRequest);
    },
```

Если делаю return data, то возвращается весь промис. В нём есть параметр [[PromiseValue]]. В нём есть текущие значения ( взять их не получается).

Comment: я же вам в прошлом вопросе показал как это сделать

Comment: Само значения получаю. Но не могу вытащить переменную data. Именно из за post запроса, не могу изменить старое состояние (this.state.names). Т.е this.state.names не может измениться при post запросе в этом промисе.

Comment: никогда не делайте так `var _this = this;`

Answer (score 0):

У вас в начале функции есть `var _this = this;`. `_this` указывает на саму компоненту. У нее есть метод `setState`.

```
.then(function (response) {
    let data = JSON.parse( response.request.response );
    // преобразуйте data к нужному виду 
    _this.setState(data);
})
```

Comment: Пока сложно понять именно этот момент. Дело в том, что при первом открытии мне возвращается статус pending http://prntscr.com/dqarwh При открытии объекта я вижу уже статус resolved http://prntscr.com/dqasg5 .  Я пока понимаю, что должен просто вызвать this.serverRequest и получить ответ на post-запрос.

Comment: вам надо разобраться как работаю promise. метод then будет вызван когда promise resolved. в response у вас будет результат запроса. вы его должны обработать и поместить в state вашей компоненты. понимаете?

Comment: Спасибо.Да область видимости нормальная, есть взять get запрос из этой статьи [ссылка](https://goo.gl/ZOksZs) . В промисе информация легко передается. Но с пост запросом совсем по-другому выходит)

Comment: опишите подробнее, что выходит по другому?

Comment: Смотрите. В этом примере [Пример] (https://goo.gl/Sia4M7)  при get запросе мы видим переменную вне промиса. Другими словами: у меня вне промиса состояние (user:[]). В промисе при get-запросе я обновляю состояние user. И в нём появляются имена. Теперь user:[Вася, Петя, Саша]. Теперь тоже самое хочу сделать в post-запросе. Но обращаясь к свойству, которое содержит массив имён (Вася, Петя..) я получаю underfined. Свойство называется PromiseValue.

Comment: какую переменную вы видите вне promise? покажите код. так как я не понимаю, что вы делаете.

Comment: В коде выше эта переменная обозначена, как data. Если изменить запрос на Get. И поставить другие данные, то переменная выводится.

Comment: переменная data не существует вне анонимной функции в then. вы не сможете ее увидеть.

Answer (score 0):

Строка запроса в `response.config.data`. 
А все предложения по адресу `response.data.suggestions`

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сохранять ответ во внешнюю переменную или стояние.

Например:

```js
componentDidMount: function() {
        var _this = this;
        let data;
        
        this.serverRequest = 
        axios.post(
            ...
        )
        .then(function (response) {
          data = response... ;
        })
       ...
    },
```

Если делать это на функциональных компонентах то лучше использовать хук состояния useState:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState(null)
useEffect(()=>{
  erverRequest = 
    axios.post(
      ...
    )
    .then(function (response) {
      setData(response...);
     })
    ...
  },
},[]
```